# Firebase cloud function cors error even when adding cors middleware

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have the following cloud function:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });


// List all surveys
exports.getSurveys = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ['TOKEN'] })
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, () => {
      // request options
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://xx1.website.com/API/v3/surveys',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-TOKEN': process.env.TOKEN,
        },
      };

      axios
        .request(options)
        .then(response => {
          res.send(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });
```

Even though I'm adding the `cors` middleware, I'm still getting an error:

Access has been blocked by CORS policy

Is this the correct way to enable `cors` in a cloud function?

In front end (react) I'm calling it like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getSurveys = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        'https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/getSurveys'
      );

      console.log(res);
    };

    getSurveys();
  }, []);
```

Comment: What is the error message in full, please?

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-<projectid>.cloudfunctions.net/getSurveys' from origin 'http://localhost:5555' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you deployed the latest version of your function? Do you see anything in the Log Explorer?

Comment: Good question sometimes I do forget but this time I did make sure to deploy latest version of the function. Nothing in the log explorer except for this relating to cors:  `at cors (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)`

Comment: In the front end (react), I'm calling it in useEffect using axios

Comment: Might be an issue with failed inner requests. You aren't sending a response or letting the function know about the failure. Try adding `res.sendStatus(500)` in your `catch` block

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')` in the function log

Comment: Have you installed and required Axios in your functions project? And I thought you said there wasn't anything in the logs

Comment: Yes `const axios = require('axios').default;`

Comment: Correct, I missed this error, now I noticed it

Comment: I tried it with jsonplaceholder and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this- In my project, I have set params in response like this and it works for me.

```
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

---

For your functions-

```
exports.getSurveys = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ['TOKEN'] })
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, () => {
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
      // request options
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://xx1.website.com/API/v3/surveys',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-API-TOKEN': process.env.TOKEN,
        },
      };

      axios
        .request(options)
        .then(response => {
          res.send(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it also didn't work. When opening the link of the cloud function in the browser, I'm getting this: `Error: could not handle the request`

Comment: I'm starting to think it might have to do with 3rd party api I'm calling. Calling the API is working in the front-end though, just not in firebase cloud functions

Comment: The cors middleware already adds those headers